# Is there any program that detects HTML and CSS errors

Tags: html, css

Is there any program or something like this, that helps to define HTML and CSS erors? so I can look at it and correct my mistakes?

Comment: W3 validator can be used.

Answer (score 0):

there are lots of website where you can check your syntax error or warning and html validate most famous website is [w3 validator](https://validator.w3.org/). here u can check your html/css errors, warning, standard/validation bu direct inputting and by uploading files

Comment: Thanks guys. I didn't know about all of this. May be , because I am a newbie

Comment: @becky try sublime text editor it will highlight your code https://www.sublimetext.com/3

Comment: Thanks. This is same as Adobe dreamweaver i guess. great

Answer (score 0):

Try to use web based validator for HTML use, [HTML Validator](https://validator.w3.org/) and for CSS use [CSS Validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/)

Or other way around is to use a good editor like [Adobe dreamweaver.](http://www.adobe.com/in/products/dreamweaver.html)

Comment: I think Adobe dreamweaver is not free to install. I did not manage to download it. ((

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://github.com/CSSLint for CSS validation. There is a plugin for grunt and gulp to use it, so you can automatically validate your code.